# Vitejs & Rollup appending 2 to javascript file name

Tags: javascript, vite, rollupjs

Configuration below for my `vitejs.config.js` file.

Running: `vite": "^4.1.4`

When I save my `./source/js/app.js` file it builds properly, however it keeps adding `2` to the file name even though there is no duplicate in there. Only disappears if I use the `[hash]` option in the `entryFileNames` option in `rollupOptions`.

Compiling creates: `./app/js/app.min2.js`

```
import { defineConfig, normalizePath } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import { viteStaticCopy } from 'vite-plugin-static-copy';
import { basename, join } from 'path';

const buildDirectory = 'app';
const themeDirName = basename(__dirname);
const staticAssets = ['media', 'fonts', 'templates'];

// We should use .env for config
// https://vitejs.dev/config/#using-environment-variables-in-config

export default defineConfig({
    publicDir: false,
    base: `/${themeDirName}/${buildDirectory}/`,
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                normalizePath(join(__dirname, './source/scss/app.scss')),
                normalizePath(join(__dirname, './source/js/app.js')),
            ],
            publicDirectory: `${buildDirectory}`,
            buildDirectory: `${themeDirName}/${buildDirectory}/`,
            refresh: ['./source/**/*.{php,twig,html}', './source/**/*.{js,scss}'],
        }),
        viteStaticCopy({
            targets: staticAssets.map(asset => ({
                src: normalizePath(join(__dirname, `./source/${asset}/*`)),
                dest: asset,
            })),
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            '~': join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        },
    },
    build: {
        manifest: false,
        emptyOutDir: false,
        outDir: normalizePath(join(__dirname, `./${buildDirectory}`)),
        assetsDir: '',
        target: 'es2021',
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                entryFileNames: 'js/[name].min.js',
                assetFileNames: '[ext]/[name][extname]',
                chunkFileNames: '[ext]/[name].[hash].js',
                dir: normalizePath(join(__dirname, `./${buildDirectory}`)),
            },
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: I recommend either checking Vite's docs or this article: https://vuejsexamples.com/how-to-config-custom-js-and-css-file-names-in-vuejs-and-vite/#:~:text=Custom%20dist%20assets%20filenames , Which Explains how to change the filenames that get output after building

Comment: Turns out it was simply because my `.scss` file and my `.js` file had the same file name... So I will check out the documents to see if that's stated anywhere otherwise might need to submit a ticket to vitejs and/or rollup